# android opengl es sharing texture between two contexts running on two threads

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, opengl-es

Main goal:

create a texture in one thread. use the texture in another thread.

What I have done so far.

1. I created two contexts and two surfaces. and made context1 and surface1 current in the main thread.

   ```
       surface1 = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, engine->app->window, NULL);
       context1 = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, attribList);
       context2 = eglCreateContext(display, config, context1, attribList);

       eglMakeCurrent(display, surface1, surface1, context1)

       eglQuerySurface(display, surface1, EGL_WIDTH, &w);
       eglQuerySurface(display, surface1, EGL_HEIGHT, &h);

       EGLint attribpbf[] =
       {
               EGL_HEIGHT, h,
               EGL_WIDTH, w,
               EGL_NONE
       };

       surface2 = eglCreatePbufferSurface(display, config, attribpbf);
   ```
2. Now I created a new thread and in that thread I made context2 and surface2 current.

   ```
   eglMakeCurrent(display, surface2, surface2, context2);
   ```
3. Then I created a texture and did some rendering into the texture and then I did glFlush();
4. I checked it here and the texture was successfully created.
5. After that tried to use this texture as a texture attachment in the main thread.But the result was a blank black screen. There was no GL error.I think the texture was not shared successfully.

Can you pleas tell me what I am doing wrong.Is there some cases when texture can not be shared .

Comment: You could try a `glIsTexture()` call in the main thread. That would tell you if the texture was shared. Even though, I think you should have gotten an error from `glGetError()` if it was not shared at all.

Comment: No luck.. glIsTexture is returning GL_TRUE and there is no gl error.Does this mean there is no issue in sharing the shader??

Comment: That makes it more likely that there's something wrong with the texture itself, or the way you are using it. Does it work if you create the same texture, with the same code, in the main thread?

Comment: Yes,everything working perfectly in the main thread with the same code.Also if I try to get the generated texture in the second thread,it is also looking good.

Comment: Hard to tell. I meant to mention: `glFlush()` will not be enough. You'll need a `glFinish()`, or some kind of fence if you can use ES 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have runing into a problem of synchronization, which means you rendering your texture in context1, and then you query the texture content immediately in context2, but the command you post to context1 was not finish yet.

And may be you can put a fence on the context1's command buffer and wait for finish in context2

reference:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFenceSync.xhtml